# Is it possible to find a context in which $A\to B$ and $\neg A\to\neg B$?

Tags: logic

I know that "if $A$ then $B$" does not mean "if $\neg A$ then $\neg B$" in the logical sense but in real life can it be possible to find a scenario that satisfies both statements and still perseveres the logic? For example, I can say if the car engine works, then the car moves. However, similarly, I can still say if there is a failure in the car engine, then the car does not move. Both statements are plausible to comprehend but not so at the logical sense, is it?

Comment: You can certainly find _particular_ sentences $A$ and $B$ such that $A\to B$ and $\neg A\to\neg B$ are both true. For example, if $A$ and $B$ are _the same_ sentence, this will automatically be the case!

Comment: This will be true for any statement whose converse is also true.

Comment: @KajHansen: what do you mean ? if a statement is both true and false, by definition it is not a statement

Comment: Sure!  The is very common.  It's if and only if.  Suppose, say .... all vampires drink blood and only vampires drink blood.  Then A= Fred drinks human blood.  B= Fred is a vampire.  If A then B.  But if -A then -B.

Comment: @fleablood: this summer I encoutered some blood drinkers which were not vampires :)

Comment: @igael He said "converse", not "negation".

Comment: Yes, and unicorns don't disolve in the rain.  We need to set up some situation where too conditions are equivalent and it came to mind... oh, I know a good one!  But it's distracting to prove it....

Comment: Let n be a natural number.  If n is a perfect square then it has an odd number of divisors.  If n is not a perfect square then n does not have an odd number of divisors.

Comment: @bof : I don't understand ; Flea or Isaacadel ? what difference here ? it depends of what is negated, no ?

Comment: But if A then B and if -A then -B are not the same thing when we plot them in a truth table. For example, if Fred drinks human blood then he is a vampire is not the same thing as: if Fred does not drink blood then he is not vampire.

Comment: @igael The converse of $A\to B$ is $B\to A.$ If the statement $A\to B$ and its converse $B\to A$ are both true, how does that make some statement "both true and false"?

Comment: @bof the subject is not on A=>B and B=>A but not A => not B. I don't see on what bit of sentence your remark applies

Comment: Your example works because we can say that "the car moves **iff** the engine works"... that is not always true: the engine is off but the car is parked on the slope without parking brake.

Comment: @igael $\neg A\to\neg B$ is equivalent to $B\to A.$

Comment: The converse of $A => B$ is $B => A$.  If both a statement and converse is true then $A <=> B$.  In those cases, A and B are "equivalent" but they are not "equal".  Whenever $A => B$ then $-B => -A$.  That's always true.  So  $A =>B$ and $-A => -B$ only occurs and always occurs if $A <=> B$.

Answer (score 2):

if A then B and if B then A ( also called A if and only if B (in short hand, A iff B)) implies not A then not B

Comment: What if A and B are not the same thing because they are different sentences?

Comment: I never said they were the same sentenence i just said
A then B and B then A, for example the  sum of the squares of the shorter legs of a triangle equals the square of longer side iff its a right triangle
A =  the  sum of the squares of the shorter legs of a triangle equals the square of longer side
B = it is a right triangle

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if

Comment: They can be different statements but they have to be equivalent meaning they are always both true or both false.

Comment: A= T is an equilateral triangle B=every angle of T is 60 degrees.  A = $\sqrt{x} $ is rational.  B = x is a perfect square C= x has an odd number of factors. D= x is the sum of the first consecutive odd number.  A,B,C,D are all equivalent.  But the are very different statements.

Comment: Suppose I have (A iff B) and if C then B, does it mean A=C? Similarly, (A iff B) and if A then C, does B=C?

Comment: if you have A iff B and if C then B, you have if C then A. if you have A off B and if A then C you have if B then C. if C then A then B in first case.

Answer (score 1):

a set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is closed and bounded $\implies S$ is compact.

a set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is not closed and bounded $\implies S$ is not compact.

Again, as mentioned above, this is because the Heine-Borel theorem is bi-conditional (if an only if). And to elaborate on the other answer provided suppose

$$[A \implies B] \wedge [\neg A \implies \neg B]$$
$$\implies [A \implies B] \wedge [B \implies A] \hspace{3mm} (\text{contraposition})$$
$$\therefore [A \iff B] \hspace{3mm} (\text{definition of bi-conditional}$$

So we just proved that anytime we have statements as you described, they $must$ be if and only if.

Comment: Prince, not ( closed and bounded ) <=> not closed or not bounded. It's a high school question, it is preferable to be simple

Comment: What information tells you it is a high school question? And what are you saying in the preceding sentence?

Comment: Were you reading what I wrote as [not closed] $\wedge$ bounded? Because I felt it was clear that since I was negating the previous line that I meant not[closed and bounded].

Comment: I was saying that your illustration of the question was false

Comment: But it's not. Quantifying over subsets $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ let $A$ bet the statement that $S$ is both closed and bounded. Let $B$ be the statement that $S$ is compact. Then $A \implies B$ and $\neg A \implies \neg B$. Just because $A = P \wedge R$ where $P = S$ is closed, $R = S$ is bounded, thus $\neg A$ = $\neg P \lor \neg R$ does not change the fact that $\neg A \implies \neg B$, no?

Comment: Here it is a matter of basic logic. In such context, you cannot negate as you did.

Comment: What is basic logic? OP did not specify what FSL system they were working in. Why can I not negate the property of a set being closed and bounded? Are you implying Heine-Borel is not iff?

Comment: Please provide a proof if my claim is false or explain why I cannot negate as such.

Comment: Your question is somehow puzzling ... Read the question and the tag, Heine Borel is not invoked here. A derived theory of the logic theory cannot constitute a proof nor an explaination. End of the comment for me.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the proposition that $x+1=2$. Let $B$ be the proposition that $x=1$. Then $A\implies B$ and $\neg A \implies \neg B$. Or equivalently, $A\iff B$.

Answer (score -1):

Sure! The is very common. It's if and only if. Suppose, say .... all vampires drink blood and only vampires drink blood. Then A= Fred drinks human blood. B= Fred is a vampire. If A then B. But if -A then -B.

But note:  in this case were $A \iff B$ there are four lesser statements, all true:

$A\implies B $

$B \implies A $

$-A \implies -B $

$-B \implies -A $

It is never the case that $A\implies B$ and $-A \implies -B $ but $B \not \implies A $.  (You can't have two without also having all four.)

Comment: ...or the middle two.  I meant the two of the OPs....

Answer (score -1):

When you declare something like : "A => B" , you are not specifically stating on A or B , you are declaring that the relation "=>" is true, no matter the trueness of A and B

Yes, it occurs that  "A => B" and "not A => not B". You may find a lot of examples, particularly when "A <=> B".

Indeed , $(A <=> B)  <=> (! A <=> ! B)$ and then it is an opportunity to say that we have both $(A => B)$  and $(! A => ! B)$ true.

Comment: "You may find a lot of examples, particularly when "A <=> B""  Um... you can *only* find example when A <=> B.

Comment: @fleablood : yes, obviously ( A=>B  and B=>A ) , but I thought that some details must be omitted to let the high school poster to understand after hints. If the remark was caming from Isaacadel , I would be very happy ... ( from you too but you are not a HS student :)